# How should I approach OAuth automated tests for google using puppeteer (node.js)

Tags: node.js, oauth, continuous-integration, automated-tests, puppeteer

I'm writing some smoke tests that would automatically run on jenkins and test the sign in with google functionality.

My problem is that when puppeteer tries to sign in with google the device is not recognized, and google asks for verification (SMS verification) which ruins my normal test flow.

Theoretically i could change the verification to email verification and write some kind process that would automatically read the email and return the authentication code and then call it in my tests. But I would strongly prefer not to create such an abomination just for sake of testing.

Is there any better way I can automate test the OAuth (google sign-in) functionality?

Comment: normally you would have a service account of some sort for these tests; the SA would not incur the same MFA rules as a typical user and the credentials for the SA are relatively locked down (ie only found via CI secrets manager of sorts)